# Need help identifying a kitchen tool, with a wooden handle, and a cylindrical cutter

Tags: utensils

I have no idea what this thing is, and it appears to be a kitchen tool, but for what?

I put up a YouTube video of it, and would love to see if anybody knows exactly what it would be used for, because we have no idea:

http://youtu.be/do5_D8Sjhk8

It would appear to be some kind of corer, or to cut shapes out of some fruit, but I can't find anything similar to it online.

[image: Mystery Kitchen Tool]

The video linked to above does a better job of showing it from multiple angles.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like one I bought a few years ago, it was suppose to cut corn off the cob. You put it around the small end of the corn and rotate in a downward motion. I didn't like the results and went back to using a knife.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely a corn cob kernel remover, and works really well. See [this video](http://youtu.be/sps9Niq62FA) for how to use it.

Comment: You already posted an answer linking to this. I see that you registered this account (and not the one you used for the previous answer), so I'm inclined to delete the previous answer and let you keep this copy. Let me know if that's not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a butter looper/curler. They are used to create a nice presentation of butter for the bread course.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butter_curler

Comment: That's the closest thing we could find so far too, except that most butter curlers found via google search tend to be less cylindrical and more more open, and thinner like the one at the wikipedia link you gave.  We tried it too, and it didn't give good results trying to curl the butter.  ;-)

Comment: alternatively, it could be an old school citrus zester, the hole on the side leads me to believe that it may be where you feed the peel out to keep it out of the cutting area.

Comment: The ribs on the cylinder and directional sawtooth suggest you torque/rotate the handle.

Answer (score 0):

The one on You Tube was opened at the side andd looked like a corn cutter and I wonder if this one doesn't have an opening too.  It looks like it but you really can't tell for sure.

My first thought was a citrus zester of yore.  It would be fun to find out.

Jo

Comment: The YouTube video was posted by the person asking the question. It's the exact tool the question's asking about. That said, the existing top answer already says it's a corn cutter; you can show your agreement simply by upvoting it (clicking the up arrow on the left side).

Comment: Yes, it's the same one as in the photo.